# CSS Background-Position not working in .class

Tags: html, css

Recentley tried to make a spritesheet with css and classes for some icons. and found that the css class doesn't work with background-position but ID does now can someone explain me why it does that.

My Actual code. I typed the my question to fast and made some mistakes sorry for that.

**This doesnt work**

```
.male {
    height: 286px;
    width: 110px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.defender {
    background: url('../images/classes/human_defender.png');
}
<div class="male defender"></div>
```

**But when i change the icon1 to an id like so it does work**

```
#male {
    height: 286px;
    width: 110px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.defender {
    background: url('../images/classes/human_defender.png');
}
<div class="defender" id="male"></div>
```

Comment: `url('backgroundimageurl')` is invalid, should be: `background-image: url('backgroundimageurl')`

Comment: you can use both **background:** and **background-image** with giving url of the image but can not use directly url coz it can't identify for what it is used.

Comment: Little out of topic... but prevent using names as "class" for classes - this does not make sense :) better is "icon" or "icons" and them for each icon clasess as "icon1, icon2" or maybe better "ico-arrow", "ico-twitter" etc...
This create more clear code - for future maintanance

Comment: I just put .class as an example ofc my actual code looks diffrent and is correct will edit my question to what my actual code looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.class {
url('backgroundimageurl');
}
```

should be

```
.class {background-image:url(backgroundimageurl);}
```

Comment: Made a mistake in my question sorry for that :D i had background: url('image'); but changing it to background-image: url('image'); did make it work :)

Comment: .class{background:url('backgroundimageurl');} should work though

Answer (score 1):

try to put and in url put path to image.

```
.class {
  background-image:url('path-to-image/image.png');
}
```

As you are saying that second option worked for you. Can you provide jsfiddle example of them ? Because mine point of view that also can't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3bssqnqj/

The JS Fiddle example putting the background: url('someimage');

TO : background-image: url('someimage'); does make it work

Answer (score 0):

In your css `.class` class has wrong background property.
Please try `background-image:url` inplace of `url`.

```css
.class {
  background-image:url('http://www.hdwallpapersos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/nature-wallpapers-natural-green-wallpaper-wallpaper.jpg');
}

.icon1 {
  background-position: 32px 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class icon1"></div>
```

Comment: tried background-image: url('myownimage'); still didnt position my image

Comment: To set position of the background,you have to set the co-ordinates of the image in "background-position" property.

Comment: changing CSS from background-image: url('someimage'); to background-image: url('someimage'); for some reason made it work couldnt edit my previous comment on this answer